# After close MudDialog page not refreshing

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, mudblazor

I try to used mud dialog to added or edit data which displaying in `MudTables`. When I added new data or edit excisting my tables not refreshing after close dialog. Only after press `F5` I can see updated dataset.

My Dialog method :

```
private async Task OpenDialog(TaxesModel tax = null){

    var parameters = new DialogParameters{{ nameof(TaxDialog.Model), tax}};
    
    DialogService.Show<TaxDialog>(nameof(TaxDialog).Humanize(), parameters);
    
    
    //reload list of taxes
    await GetTaxesAsync();
    StateHAsChanged();
    }
```

In this case `StateHAsChanged()` not refreshed page. But in another cases without dialog it's work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are refreshing the data as soon as the dialog opens, before any change has happened yet to the database. After the call to `DialogService.Show` the execution continues immidiately to the next line `await GetTaxesAsync()`.

You need to wait for dialog to close and then fetch the new data.

```
private async Task OpenDialog(TaxesModel tax = null){

    var parameters = new DialogParameters{ { nameof(TaxDialog.Model), tax } };

    var dialog = DialogService.Show<TaxDialog>(nameof(TaxDialog).Humanize(), parameters);
    
    // wait for the dialog to close
    // execution is stopped here until the dialog returns a result
    var result = await dialog.Result;

    if (!result.Cancelled)
    {
        await GetTaxesAsync();
        // StateHasChanged call is not needed I think
        //StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

https://mudblazor.com/components/dialog#passing-data